# Ball movement path in canvas, and other ideas you may have?

Tags: html, animation, canvas, physics

I've created this animation for my project that had to use any form of physics.
I am a total beginner, too :) Anyway, this is my project now :

[Bouncing Balls](http://www.ii.uj.edu.pl/~kadluczs/MiSK-fresh/)

You can setup gravity and force, then click play, and just drag and drop to shoot the balls. You can change the values and hit update too see an effect.

My question is, how can I create an effect that when I press ratio button (for example) I can see the path that ball makes? Is it complicated? As I was saying I am a beginner, so no complex code for me :)

Also, doyou have any ideas to make the project better? Any additional "physics" effects? Or maybe you know a website that shows tutorials for simile (please) effects made in HTML5/js so I can add additional effects to my project.

Comment: You could add collision between the balls, or maybe add another slider in which you change the restitution (amount of energy loss at each bounce) or air drag with a adjustable viscosity slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility (as you're clearing the canvas each frame) would be to draw ball paths onto a secondary canvas, which would not be cleared each frame. Then, when you come to clear the first frame, render the second frame after clearing, and before rendering the balls.

The second canvas would of course have to be the same dimensions as the first, so that all of the ball points line up correctly. The second canvas should also have a z-index lower than the first, so that it is only shown when you specifically render it to the first canvas (i.e. when the radio button is checked).

To decrease any lag while the radio is not checked, you could skip drawing the ball paths to the second canvas, although I don't think you would see any great increase in performance.

On each frame update, you would mark the position of each ball with a pixel, or line (from the previous position to the current) on the second canvas.

Looking at your code, you seem pretty competent, so I've skipped writing an example as I think this would be good experience for you :)

**Modified 'script.js' source demonstrating solution**

```
window.onload = function(){
    $("#canvas").hide();

    var howManyPaths = 0;   
    var showPath=false;

    // SLIDERS
    var gravitySlider = document.getElementById('gravitySlider');
    var gravityVal = document.getElementById('gravityValue');

    gravitySlider.onchange = function(){
        gravityVal.value = gravitySlider.value;
    }

    gravityVal.onkeyup = function(){
          gravitySlider.value = gravityVal.value;      
    } 

    var forceSlider = document.getElementById('forceSlider');
    var forceValue = document.getElementById('forceValue');

    forceSlider.onchange = function(){
        forceValue.value = forceSlider.value;
    }

    forceValue.onkeyup = function(){
          forceSlider.value = forceValue.value;      
    } 

    // GLOBAL VARIABLES
    var test = false;
    var gravityCount = $("#gravity").val();
    var forceCount = $("#rectangles").val();    

    // CSS :
    var playCSS = document.getElementById("play");
    var restartCSS = document.getElementById("restart");
    var clickableCSS = document.getElementById("setup");
    var clickableBG = document.getElementById("img");

    //restartCSS.style.visibility="hidden";

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");


    //var ctx;
    var gravity = 9.86;
    var forceFactor = 0.5;
    var mouseDown = false;
    var balls = new Array();
    var mousePos = new Array();

    // EVENT HANDLER
    function onMouseDown(evt){
        mouseDown = true;
        mousePos['downX'] = evt.pageX;
        mousePos['downY'] = evt.pageY;
    }

    function onMouseUp(evt){
        mouseDown = false;


        setup.style.visibility="visible";


        if(test == true && !( mousePos['downX'] < 200 && mousePos['downY'] < 150) ){

        restartCSS.style.visibility="visible";

        forceFactor = forceCount;



        balls.push(new ball(mousePos["downX"],
                            mousePos["downY"],
                            (evt.pageX - mousePos["downX"]) * forceFactor,
                            (evt.pageY - mousePos["downY"]) * forceFactor,
                            10 + (Math.random() * 10),
                            0.8,
                            randomColor()
                    ));
        }
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
    }

    function onMouseMove(evt){
        mousePos['currentX'] = evt.pageX;
        mousePos['currentY'] = evt.pageY;   
    }

    function resizeWindow(evt){
        //canvas.height = 960;
        //canvas.width = 720;
        canvas.height = $(window).height()-6;
        canvas.width = $(window).width();

        canvas2.height = $(window).height()-6;
        canvas2.width = $(window).width();
    }

    $(document).mousedown(onMouseDown);
    $(document).mouseup(onMouseUp);
    $(document).mousemove(onMouseMove);

    $(window).bind("resize", resizeWindow);

    // GRAPHICS CODE
        function circle(x, y, r, col){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
            ctx.closePath;

            // fill         
            ctx.fillStyle = col;
            ctx.fill();

            // stroke
            ctx.lineWidth = r * 0.1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.stroke();   
}




function circlePath(x, y)
{
    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
    ctx2.fillStyle = '#3f4043';
    ctx2.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
    ctx2.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx2.strokeRect(x, y, 5, 5);
}





        function randomColor(){
            var letter = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");
            var color = "#";

            for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
                color += letter[Math.round(Math.random()*15)];  
            }

            return color;
            }

        function arrow(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, color){
            // path
            ctx.beginPath();
            var headLen = 10;
            var angle = Math.atan2(toY - fromY, toX - fromX);
            ctx.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
            ctx.lineTo(toX, toY);

            ctx.lineTo(toX - headLen * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI/6), toY - headLen * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI/6));
            ctx.moveTo(toX, toY);
            ctx.lineTo(toX - headLen * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/6), toY - headLen * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/6));

            // style
            ctx.lineWith = 1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.lineCap = "butt";
            ctx.stroke();
        }


        function drawBall(){

            // Gravity
            gravity = gravityCount;

            this.speedY += gravity * 0.5; // v = a * t
            this.x += this.speedX * 0.05; // s = v * t
            this.y += this.speedY * 0.05;

            // prawa ściana
            if(this.x + this.r > canvas.width){
                this.x = canvas.width - this.r;
                this.speedX *= -1 * this.bounce;    
            }

            // lewa ściana
            if(this.x - this.r < 0){
                this.x = this.r;
                this.speedX *= -1 * this.bounce;    
            }

            // dolna ściana
            if(this.y + this.r > canvas.height){
                this.y = canvas.height - this.r;
                this.speedY *= -1 * this.bounce;

            }

            // górna ściana
            if(this.y - this.r < 0){
                this.y = this.r;
                this.speedY *= -1 * this.bounce;
            }

                        // zwalnianie na ziemi
            if (this.speedX > 0.25){
                this.speedX -= 0.25;
                    if (this.speedY > 0.25)
                        this.speedY -= 0.25;
            }

            if (this.speedX < -0.25){
                this.speedX += 0.25;
                    //if (this.speedY < -0.25)
                    //  this.speedY += 0.25;
            }

            circle(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.col);;

        }

    // OBJECTS
        function ball(positionX, positionY, sX, sY, radius, b, color){
            this.x = positionX;
            this.y = positionY;
            this.speedX = sX;
            this.speedY = sY;
            this.r = radius;
            this.bounce = b;    
            this.col = color;

            this.draw = drawBall;
        }

    //GAME LOOP
        function gameLoop(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            //grab the context from your destination canvas

            //if path drawing is enabled, first draw the path canvas to the display canvas
            if (showPath) ctx.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);

            if(mouseDown == true){
                 // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); /* !important !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
                 arrow(mousePos['downX'], mousePos['downY'], mousePos['currentX'], mousePos['currentY'], "red");
            }

            for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++){
                balls[i].draw();
                if (i==balls.length-1) {
                    //draw path
                    ctx2.fillStyle = '#3f4043';
                    ctx2.fillRect(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, 5, 5);
                    ctx2.strokeStyle = "black";
                    ctx2.strokeRect(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, 5, 5);     
                }
            }

            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.font = "15px Arial";
            ctx.fillText("Balls: " + balls.length + " " + gravityCount + " " + forceCount + " " + howManyPaths, 10, canvas.height -10);

        }
    // START THE GAME
    function init(){
        //$("#setup").hide();
        $("#canvas").show();
        $("#canvas2").hide();
        ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext("2d");      
        canvas.height = $(window).height()-6;
        canvas.width = $(window).width();
        //canvas.width = 960;
        //canvas.height = 720;
        canvas2.height = $(window).height()-6;
        canvas2.width = $(window).width();
        return setInterval(gameLoop, 10);
    }

    $("#play").click(function() {   
        test = true;
        playCSS.style.visibility="hidden";
        gravityCount = $("#gravitySlider").val();
        forceCount = $("#forceSlider").val();
        init();

    });

    $("#restart").click(function() {    
        window.location.href="index.html";
    });

    $("#refresh").click(function() {    
        gravityCount = $("#gravitySlider").val();
        forceCount = $("#forceSlider").val();
    }); 

    $("#showPath").click(function() {   
        showPath=true;
    }); 

    $("#hidePath").click(function() {   
        showPath=false;
    });
}
```

Comment: http://www.ii.uj.edu.pl/~kadluczs/MiSK-fresh/
I've managed to create a path (for 2 seconds, I will add an option to choose how long the path will be) but it only creates the path for first ball..

I've tried every reseting/clearing canvas method on the web, and no luck.. How can I clear the canvas entirely and not just hide it and be able to draw a path for last ball I create (mouse click up means new ball). A code would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, you're almost there. Instead of showing / hiding the second canvas, draw the second canvas to the first on each frame if a boolean (let's say called 'showPath') is true. I've updated my answer with the modified 'script.js' source. Take note of the changes to the draw loop, and to the showPath and hidePath button click binds.

Comment: Well, it works fine for an animation, but still, it draws multiple paths as opposed to 1. I guess it's not possible, or harder to implement to clear the canvas entirely when shooting new ball. Not clear once and let other balls be shown afterwards.

What I mean : Show always only ONE path (the last ball's path) no matther what :)

Comment: Aha - well if you only want it for one ball, whenever you create a new ball, clear the rect of the second context! :)

Comment: I tried, but it's not working :(

function onMouseUp(evt){
...
ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
}

I tried adding it at the end and it clears the rect, indeed, but the you shoot a second ball, new path is being drawn AND STILL the paths of other balls - those are at the bottom by then, but function loops the drawing, so it's not dissapearing entirely.

It's just being cleared once, and then the paths are being drawn again for all of the balls.

Comment: Ah sorry, I got that completely wrong. Check out the updated code in my post. We're now clearing the second context when adding a new ball, and only drawing the path if the current 'i' value in the loop is equal to the last possible 'i' value in the loop :)

Comment: As this appears to be a project for a course of some kind, I'd recommend not relying on others to completely do the work for you. Read through the base code you've got, understand what it's doing and improvise a solution. You will learn nothing if you just copy and paste others work. Programming is all about finding solutions to problems, and if you're looking to go into programming as a profession, these skills will be essential. Just some friendly advice.

Comment: I did it off a tutorial from YouTube.
I'm trying to learn, that's why I ddin't simply copy it, I wanted to add more functionality to it :)

Thank you, it finally is working the way I imagined! THANKS!!